# Invalid user credentials in MySQL parameterized query

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

It shows invalid user credentials even though I inputted the right one. I don't know if I made the parameters wrong or if my query is wrong. I want to learn about parameterized queries but I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
con.OpenConnection();

        using (con.connection)
        {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password";
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con.connection);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid user credentials.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException mse)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(mse.Message); 
            }

            finally
            {
                con.CloseConnection();
            }
```

Comment: Can you share the exception message you are getting?

Comment: where is `i` defined.. also is it a string or an Integer..
`i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());` 
if i is an integer then you do not need to do the conversion just set i = to the count like this 
`var i = dt.Rows.Count;`

Comment: @hbulens i do not get an exception message. I think with the code i wrote it the if statement returns true because it didnt match with the parameters. im no sure tho.

Comment: @MethodMan i is an integer, i defined it outside the using clause. Will try out not adding the Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString()); tho

Comment: you are executing the query.. then you are trying to fill it after it's been executed.. I will post a simple way for you to do this.. `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Normally used for UPDATES, DELETES, INSERTS` Look up ExecuteScalar method in the meantime

Comment: comment out this line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` you don't need it.. when you call the `.Fill()` Method it will execute the Select Query for you..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not working but if you use AddWithValue, it will work. Something like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
```

Comment: AddWithValue() can have significant unexpected performance penalties. Generally best to be explicit about your parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code so that it's calls a method, when you click on a Button, pass the Username and Password variable into this Method. Create a AutoProperty for UserName and Password at the Class Level

```
private DataTable PopulateSomeDatatSet(DataSet aDataset, string UserName, string Password)
{
    var query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE Username = @Username and Password = @Password";
    MySqlDataAdapter sda;
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(ConnString)) //replace with your ConnectionString Variable
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connStr))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Password;
            sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(aDataset);
        }
    }
    ((IDisposable)sda).Dispose();
    return aDataset.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: Like this?
            String user = txtUsername.Text;
            String pass = txtPassword.Text;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            i = PopulateSomeDatatSet(adaset, user, pass).Rows.Count;

Comment: Why are you casting the MySqlDataAdapter to IDiposable? Why not call dispose on it directly? Why aren't you disposing it in a finally block or using a `using` statment?